# Prove this set is finite for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A$ be an infinite set and let $f:$ $A \to [0,\infty)$ be a function.  If the set $\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(a_k): a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A \text{ distinct and } n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$ is bounded we write $\sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a)$ to denote its supremum, otherwise we write $\sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a) = \infty$.

If $\sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a) < \infty$, then show that set $A_n = \{a \in A: f(a) \geq 1/n\}$ is finite for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I know that $\sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a) < \infty$ implies that $\left\{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(a_k): a_1, \ldots, a_n \in A \text{ distinct and } n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}\ $ 
(let's call this set $F$) is bounded.  It seems like induction would be logical here, but the problem is that $A_n$ grows with $n$, so recursion may be a better choice.  I also feel like the obvious fact that $A_n$ is bounded below (and above?) will be useful.  Otherwise I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Suppose for some $n$, $A_n$ is infinite. What can you say about $\sum\limits_{a \in A_n} f(a)$? and what does this say about $\sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a)$?

Comment: @claycrusher if it were not finite, then $\sum_{a \in A} f(a)$ would diverge as it would be bigger than a harmonic series

Comment: @PaulSinclair If $A_{n}$ were infinite, then $\sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a) \geq 1/n$ for all $a \in A$  Edit: wait that's wrong.  I'm not sure.

Comment: Though Anthony Peter has since clarified, my point was if $A_n$ is infinite, then the sum over just it is of an infinite number of elements $\ge {1\over n}$, and therefore is infinite, and since the sum over all $A$ is $\ge$ the sum over $A_n$, it must be infinite as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $A_n$ is infinite for some $n$. Then, there are infinitely many $a \in A$ such that $f(a) \geq \frac{1}{n}$.This implies

$$\sum_{a \in A} f(a) \geq \sum_{a \in A_n} f(a) \geq \sum_{j=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{j} = \infty,$$ so $$\sum_{a \in A} f(a)$$ would diverge by comparison with the harmonic series, a contradiction.

Comment: Ugh I thought it was something along these lines, but I hadn't thought of proving by contradiction and was trying to prove that the series converged since it had a lower and upper bound.  Thanks!

Comment: @Claycrusher No worries, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

If  $S = \sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a) < \infty$ and $a_1,\ldots, a_k \in A_n $ are distinct then
$$
 S = \sum\limits_{a \in A} f(a) \ge \sum_{j=1}^k f(a_j) \ge \sum_{j=1}^k \frac 1n = \frac kn
$$
It follows that $k \le n\cdot S$, i.e. $A_n$ has at most $n\cdot S$ elements.

Comment: But aren't you assuming in the second equality that $A_{n}$ is finite?

Comment: @Claycrusher: No, I am assuming only that $A_n$ has at least $k$ (distinct) elements $a_1, \ldots, a_k$. But the (in)equality chain was perhaps misleading, I have fixed that now. The first inequality follows from the definition of the supremum.

Comment: Ok that makes sense.  I like how this bypasses anything to do with infinity.  Thank you!